# Python Pandas - add comment for respective filtered cell

Tags: pandas, filter, contains

I have data in `excel` like below.

I am new for python `pandas`,  I know a little bit  like how to import `excel` and filter `>` in a column but I want to know how to do `contains` on `[City]` column like ( "contains = TN").

If it's "TN" then create a new column and make a `[Note]` in respective cell (like below note column).

And filter on age, if `[Age] > 30` then add a note on `[Note]` column.

Please someone help on this....

```
[Name]      【Age】        【City】             【Note】

Chandru,.     29,           chennai TN,         Contain TN

John,         43,           Mumbai MH,          age >30

George,       35,           Madurai TN,         Contain TN | age >30

Karthik.,     25,           Kolkata WB
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I got this. You want to import an excel spreadsheet in Pandas and create another column based on the values of city and age?

Comment: you can read the excel file into pandas as dataframe and then use `df.apply(get_notes,axis=1)`, `get_notes` is a function where you can write your conditions and return suitable string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that your excel spreadsheet is called my_file.xlsx, the following code using Pandas and Numpy creates the Note column in the dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('my_file.xlsx')
df['Note'] = np.where((df.Age > 30) & df.City.str.contains('TN'), 'Contain TN | age >30',
             np.where((df.Age > 30) & ~df.City.str.contains('TN'), 'age >30',
             np.where(~(df.Age > 30) & df.City.str.contains('TN'), 'Contain TN', '')))
```

This produces the following dataframe:

[image]

If you want to know more about the np.where() method, the link for the official documentation containing examples are:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: Does this answer address correctly your question? If so, would you mind select and upvote it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, I got below error when i used following query for different column - df['Note'] = df.Email.str.contains('@@'), 'Email contains @@',''   (ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index)

Comment: With a different structure, is not easy to understand what is going on. If the data is in another format, you should edit your question.

Comment: I have a email column in the excel sheet. on the email column, some of the email contains '@@". so i want to find those records and mark on the note column.

Comment: You can use something like: df['Note'] = np.where(df.Email.str.contains('@@').fillna(False), 'Email contains @@', '' ). But it will just comment on this specific condition.